# How can I do a MouseOver of exact image shape?

Tags: javascript, html, implementation

The question below is not really a programming question, but more of "how can I do this" question, implementation advice.

I have an image of the world map. I can make each continent a separate image.

What I want to do is create a hover over feature for each continent. When the users mouse is over the continent - the **EXACT** shape of the continent that is - I want it to change colour.

My main question is, how can I reference when the users mouse is over the **exact** shape of the continent? I do not want to use Flash for this, all though I am afraid there is no other way to do this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this (without external libraries or js) is using `<map>`. You will have to put in the coords and shape (in this case poly for the shape) to match the area you want to allow: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp

Comment: Thank you for that, didn't know the <map> could do other shapes other than a square/rectangle!

Comment: Np. Obviously, the "exactness" of the poly is up to your sanity, but you could theoretically get it to match near 100%.

Comment: You can export paths from GIMP to svg files. These you can edit with geany and excel to convert them to AREA "poly" coördinates: (1) Open the file with geany to select the "d" value of the path node (skip the rows M and C. (2) Replace tabs and comma's to spaces (use \t escape character) (3) paste the data in excel to remove decimal numbers (4) copy columns 1 and 2 (5) paste into geany (6) replace tabs and newlines to commas (use \n escape character)

Answer (score 5):

In answer to your main question, you'll probably need to use a good old image map. [This image map generator](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap) has worked well for me in the past.

As for making them change colors, you could always use a sprite and just change the background position of each country on hover?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into this jQuery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight

and theres a tutorial here:
http://www.electricfairground.com/2009/08/08/image-map-rollover-effects-using-jquerys-maphilight-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your platform (web, winform, linux, os x, etc.).

On the web, you can use an image map.

On any OS-hosted application, you could do the equivalent of an image map using a region.  Or you could even test the color of the pixel over which you are hovering.